# how can I keep the dos box open when executing a perl program from windows explorer?

Tags: windows, perl, cmd

I can run a perl program by typing its name into the command line. (without calling perl)

But if I click on it in windows explorer, the dos box flashes on and immediately closes.

The dos box will stay up if I make a batch file that calls the program, and click on that.

But needing 2 files to execute a program is kind of a kloodge.

Is there some other way to make the dos box stay open when I click on the filename in explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not specific to perl, the window will close when you run any text mode program from Windows explorer (e.g. click `ipconfig.exe` and the window will close immediately).

If you often run Perl scripts by clicking the files in Explorer I suggest that you write a `perl.bat` in your `bin` directory near `perl.exe` with the contents like

```
@echo off
perl.exe %*
pause
```

and associate this `.bat` file with Perl scripts. As a consequence, you will also need to press any key when running scripts from the command line which may be boring.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure a shortcut that is set to stay open.

Or you can edit your Perl script to wait for input before closing.

```
END {
    print "Press enter to exit\n";
    <>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Miller. But how do I configure a shortcut to stay open? I see no such option in the shortcut creation dialog.