# Compiled Perl script does not produce expected output, uncompiled script does

Tags: windows, perl, compilation

I am a beginner.

I compiled my Perl script using pp (PAR::Packer) for Windows. When I run it, the expected output files are not produced.  When I run the script un-compiled, the files are produced.
The compiler did not give me any error message or warning.

How can I continue with the debugging?

I can share code segments but not the whole thing, unfortunately.  I tried to replicate the failure with a simplified case but that ran correctly.

Any pointer is appreciated.

The community bot asked me to provide code.  Here is some.

The beginning and the end of the script ***z5in.pl***:

```
use feature ':5.10';
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my $inputFile = '../_zmpl2-out_instanceBlocks.txt';
my $schOutputFile = '../_zmpl5-out_schematicStats.txt';
my $userOutputFile = '../_zmpl5-out_userStats.txt';

my %instanceBlocks;

my %iFieldHash;
my $instanceKey = '';
my $instanceProperty = '';
my $currentSch = '';
my $currentUser = '';
my $currentComponent = '';
my $currentGrid = '';
my %schHash;
my %userHash;

open INPUTFILE, "<".$inputFile or die "Couldn't open $inputFile: $!";
```

... then the body of the script and then where I should write the results:

```
open OUTPUTFILE, ">".$schOutputFile or die "Couldn't open $schOutputFile: $!";
foreach my $schematic (sort keys %schHash) {
    printf OUTPUTFILE "\n$schematic ";
    foreach (sort keys $schHash{$schematic}) {
            printf OUTPUTFILE "$_=$schHash{$schematic}{$_} ";
            }
    }
close OUTPUTFILE;


open OUTPUTFILE, ">".$userOutputFile or die "Couldn't open $userOutputFile: $!";
foreach my $user (sort keys %userHash) {
    my $nok = keys $userHash{$user};
    printf OUTPUTFILE "$user $nok\n";
    foreach (sort keys $userHash{$user}) {
            printf OUTPUTFILE "$_=$userHash{$user}{$_}\n";
            }
    printf OUTPUTFILE "\n";
    }
close OUTPUTFILE;
```

I compiled this using
`pp -o z5out.exe z5in.pl`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which version of perl and Windows are you using?

Comment: *"When I run it, the expected output files are not produced."* What happens if you print the files to the terminal instead? Does the output appear on the terminal?

Comment: This is perl 5, version 32, subversion 1 (v5.32.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

Windows10

Comment: I will try printing to the terminal.  Good idea, thanks.

Comment: Printing to the terminal makes no difference. When the executable runs, a command shell window pops up for a split second and disappears.

Comment: @Zoltan *"a command shell window pops up for a split second and disappears"* Try  to pause the program at the end to see the output and prevent the shell window from closing, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26053452/2173773) question for an example

Comment: How do you invoke the script? How do you invoke the packed executable? Did you try absolute filepaths?

Comment: The script I just run from within my IDE (Padre).  The Windows executable I just invoke from within a shell (cmd.exe)  without any command line arguments.. As simple as it gets.

Comment: For some inexplicable reason the problem has gone away.  My completely uninstalling all Perl (I had both Strawberry and Dwimperl in my system) and reinstalling only Dwimperl (my IDE needs that) may have something to do with it.  Thanks for all the pointers, though.